# Exact value of two variables need to be compared in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
$j('#row1').find('span.grpid').each(function() {
        groupIdNew = groupId.split("~")[0];
        var value = $j(this).html();
        if (value.match(groupIdNew)){
            $j(this).parents('tr').remove();
        }
    });
```

Problem is I need the value to exactly equal groupIdNew. (Eg: `test_11` should not match `test_1` as is the case with `.match()`, but exactly equal `test_11`). How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the double equals sign?

```
if (value == groupIdNew) {
```

Use the triple if you want to be strict about the data types.

Comment: Or even the triple equation sign to match also type.

if (value === groupIdNew) {

Comment: @Oscar - *"Use the triple if you want to be strict about the data types."* - this answer does say that.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `match`, just compare them:

```
if(value === groupIdNew){
```

Or if you need to trim whitespace:

```
if($j.trim(value) === groupIdNew){
```

Comment: I would probably use jQuery's `$.trim()`, as IE8 doesn't support native `.trim()` - although, the OP didn't say anything about whitespace.

Comment: @ahren Good point, I'll edit. The reason I mention trim is that I figure the OP may have already tried doing comparison like this and had unexpected results before trying `match`.  The most likely situation for that I think would be if they have whitespace they aren't noticing that they need to trim.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `if(value === groupIdNew){`

you can use the triple if you want to be strict about the data type

Answer (score 0):

use `===` operator

```
 if (value === groupIdNew){
        $j(this).parents('tr').remove();
    }
```

Comment: If the variables are of the same type, you should use `===` to enforce strict type checking.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it using the equal operator (===):

```
if (value === groupIdNew){
```

Here's the full code:

```
$j('#row1').find('span.grpid').each(function() {
        groupIdNew = groupId.split("~")[0];
        var value = $j(this).html();
        if (value === groupIdNew){
            $j(this).parents('tr').remove();
        }
});
```

Comment: You should use `===` to enforce strict type checking if the values are of the same type.